# seq_along of two lists, make a dataframe and keep the name of the lists

Tags: r, dataframe, list, sequence, names

I have two lists and I want all the elements of the one list to be combined with all
the elements of the second list. I want to create a dataframe with column names of those
combinations. I am not able to keep the names of the lists while indexing by using the seq_along
function.

My two lists

```
mylist_2 <-list(c("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8", "b9"))
mylist_1 <-list(c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6"))

#making a vector with the length of multuplying the two:
mylist_f <- vector("list", length = length(mylist_1)*length(mylist_2))
```

I want to have a dataframe and the column names will be their combination

```
datafr <- expand.grid(i = seq_along(mylist_2), j = seq_along(mylist_1))[2:1]

## an under score will connect the indexing
data_fr <- apply(data_fr, 1, paste, collapse = "_")
names(mylist_f) <- datafr
```

What I get is:

```
>[1] "1_1" "1_2" "1_3" "1_4" "1_5" "1_6" "1_7" "1_8" "1_9" "2_1" "2_2" "2_3" "2_4" "2_5" "2_6"
[16] "2_7" "2_8" "2_9" "3_1" "3_2" "3_3" "3_4" "3_5" "3_6" "3_7" "3_8" "3_9" "4_1" "4_2" "4_3"
[31] "4_4" "4_5" "4_6" "4_7" "4_8" "4_9" "5_1" "5_2" "5_3" "5_4" "5_5" "5_6" "5_7" "5_8" "5_9"
[46] "6_1" "6_2" "6_3" "6_4" "6_5" "6_6" "6_7" "6_8" "6_9"
```

I am getting the indexing of the two lists but I would like to keep the name of the lists,I would like to get:

```
"a1_b1", "a1_b2", "a1_b3",......"a1_b9", 
"a2_b1", "a2_b2",....."a2_b9", "a3_b1", "a3_b2", "a3_b3"....."a3_b9",.....
```

Any ideas how to keep the name of the lists on the columns of the dataframe?

Comment: Im curious what you think the names of the lists are ? do you mean `mylist_1` and `mylist_2` ? I wonder but those symbols dont appear in the 'I would like to get section; it seems the 'names' part of your issue is irrelevant and your sole focus is to combine the contents with a `_` seperator ...  can you clarify ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `expand.grid` to get the combinations from the two lists, then `apply` to `paste` the values together:

```
apply(expand.grid(unlist(mylist_1), unlist(mylist_2)), 1,
      paste, collapse = "_")
```

Output:

```
# [1] "a1_b1" "a2_b1" "a3_b1" "a4_b1" "a5_b1" "a6_b1" "a1_b2" "a2_b2" "a3_b2" "a4_b2" "a5_b2" "a6_b2" "a1_b3" "a2_b3"
# [15] "a3_b3" "a4_b3" "a5_b3" "a6_b3" "a1_b4" "a2_b4" "a3_b4" "a4_b4" "a5_b4" "a6_b4" "a1_b5" "a2_b5" "a3_b5" "a4_b5"
# [29] "a5_b5" "a6_b5" "a1_b6" "a2_b6" "a3_b6" "a4_b6" "a5_b6" "a6_b6" "a1_b7" "a2_b7" "a3_b7" "a4_b7" "a5_b7" "a6_b7"
# [43] "a1_b8" "a2_b8" "a3_b8" "a4_b8" "a5_b8" "a6_b8" "a1_b9" "a2_b9" "a3_b9" "a4_b9" "a5_b9" "a6_b9"
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is `outer`:

```r
c(outer(mylist_1[[1]], mylist_2[[1]], function(a, b) paste(a, b, sep = "_")))
#  [1] "a1_b1" "a2_b1" "a3_b1" "a4_b1" "a5_b1" "a6_b1" "a1_b2" "a2_b2" "a3_b2" "a4_b2" "a5_b2" "a6_b2" "a1_b3" "a2_b3" "a3_b3" "a4_b3" "a5_b3" "a6_b3" "a1_b4"
# [20] "a2_b4" "a3_b4" "a4_b4" "a5_b4" "a6_b4" "a1_b5" "a2_b5" "a3_b5" "a4_b5" "a5_b5" "a6_b5" "a1_b6" "a2_b6" "a3_b6" "a4_b6" "a5_b6" "a6_b6" "a1_b7" "a2_b7"
# [39] "a3_b7" "a4_b7" "a5_b7" "a6_b7" "a1_b8" "a2_b8" "a3_b8" "a4_b8" "a5_b8" "a6_b8" "a1_b9" "a2_b9" "a3_b9" "a4_b9" "a5_b9" "a6_b9"
```

Comment: You may simplify to `c(t(outer(el(mylist_1), el(mylist_2), paste, sep='_')))`.

Comment: Very good point on what I mean names.

Comment: What I want is instead of the indexing to get the names of the elements of my lists:

Comment: @MariaK, the sample data a few comments ago do not look like the samples you provided in your question. Both answers (so far) use the old format and gave precisely what you asked for, so if you want something different then you need to update your sample data, and please make it "real" enough, since `list(a1=c(h,b,c))` is going to fail with `object 'h' not found`.

Comment: Very good point on what I mean names.

Comment: That is my data_fr 
   j i
1  1 1
2  1 2
3  1 3
4  1 4
5  1 5
6  1 6
7  1 7
8  1 8
9  1 9
10 2 1
11 2 2
12 2 3
13 2 4
14 2 5
15 2 6
...
> data_fr <- apply(data_fr, 1, paste, collapse = "_")
> data_fr
 [1] "1_1" "1_2" "1_3" "1_4" "1_5" "1_6" "1_7" "1_8" "1_9" "2_1" "2_2" "2_3" "2_4" "2_5" "2_6" "2_7" "2_8" "2_9" "3_1" "3_2" "3_3"...... Not be the indexes but to rename them and match the names of the lists. At the same time I need the j and i indexes as later they enter a for loop.

Comment: So I need data_fr j i to be b1_a1, b1_a2,b1_a3,b1_a4,b1_a6,b2_a1,b2_a2.....

Comment: Please recognize that data in comments does not show very well; at a minimum, I can't tell if `data_fr` is a matrix or a frame, nor how many columns/rows it has. Furthermore, this new data is relevant to the whole question, so please edit your question and add the updated data in a [code block].

Comment: list1<-list(c(a1=(...), a2=(...), a3= (...),...a6=(...)), my second list2<-list(c(b1=(...),b2=(...)...b9). The way my code is written the data_fr has two columns j i that keeps as elements the indexes of the lists. I want my data_fr to have are the names of the elements of my lists instead e.g. j i a1 b1 a1 b2 a1 b3....Is this possible?

Comment: Data in comments does not show very well. I'm not being pedantic, I'm being practical. We don't have your data, and the BEST way to give us data is to give us _actual data_, not an abbreviated-text approximation.